# Resolving Kubernetes services by name across clusters on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Would a service in cluster `a` calling a service `be-service` be able to resolve to pod in cluster `b` under some networking setups?

[image]

Thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (resolving services by name across clusters) doesn't exist today.

However, take a look at [Setting up clusters with shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-shared-vpc) documentation to learn more about how you can have multiple clusters in the same VPC, so you can access a service in another cluster through its **IP address**.

Similarly, GKE supports [Internal load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) which makes your cluster's services accessible to applications outside of your cluster (like a GCE VM) that use the same VPC network and that are located in the same GCP region.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Internal Load [Balancers](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) to make a service running on GKE to be reached from other GCE VMs or other GKE clusters in the same network.

In order to resolve a pod you need to use [VPC-native clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips)